# Get the name of the image resource used in image button

Tags: android, button, android-resources

I'm new to Android programming and I want to know that how can I get the name of the  image resource that is currently set on the image button.
eg :  b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
//where b1 is the image button and img is the name of the png file present in res/drawable.

Now I would like to know how would I get the name of the image file i.e "img".
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setTag() and getTag() this way you can store any data you want.

```
imageView.setTag("imageNameHere");
String imageName = (String) imageView.getTag();
```

Let me know! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are simply looking to add an image as a background to your button.

To do this, add your chosen image to your res/drawable folder (there are many ways to do this). You can rename it if you like, but I recommend lowercase with underscores ( _ ), like "img_1", or just "img" as you have said.

Then, in your XML view, add the **android:background** line to your button...

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/img"/>
```

Comment: No I was making a tic tac toe game and wanted to change the images dynamically in Java code. But thanks anyways:)